# Emberjs how to create a new belongsTo item

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm working on a simple todo app where each todo item belongs to a user. I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'createTodo'.
```

I think I'm missing a route and maybe a controller, but I'm not really sure what I need to do.

**app/router.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: TodoENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: ':user_id'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

**app/routes/users/index.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});
```

**app/models/user.js:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  todos: DS.hasMany('todo')
});
```

**app/models/todo.js:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

**app/controllers/todo.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    createTodo: function() {
      var title = this.get('newTitle');
      if (!title.trim()) { return; }

      var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
        title: title // how do I get the user id?
      });

      this.set('newTitle', '');

      todo.save();
    }
  }
});
```

**app/templates/users/show.hbs:**

```
<h4>{{name}}</h4>

<h5>Todos</h5>
{{input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="new todo"
      value=newTitle action="createTodo"}}
<ul>
  {{#each todos}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is `createTodo` being called from?

Comment: createTodo is called from the input box in app/templates/users/show.hbs

Comment: cna you create a jsbin to duplicate this issue ?

Comment: I uploaded the code to GitHub: https://github.com/oblakeerickson/todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is createTodo is implemented in TodoController whereas you are using `createTodo` action in `users/show` template. Action is sent to the `UsersShowController` where createTodo is not implemented. Move `createTodo` action into `UsersShowController` and everything should be OK.